# SQL запрос не видит параметры

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, postgresql, c#-8.0

Я делаю следующие команды в windows forms c#.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("DO $$ BEGIN IF EXISTS(select id from clients where id=@cnumberclient) THEN INSERT INTO reservations(roomnumber,clientnumber,datein, dateout) values(@rnumber, @cnumber, @din, @dout); ELSE raise notice 'HYI'; END IF; END $$;", conn.getConnection());
command.Parameters.Add("@cnumber", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ClientId;
command.Parameters.Add("@cnumberclient", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ClientId;
command.Parameters.Add("@rnumber", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = RoomId;
command.Parameters.Add("@din", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = dateIn;
command.Parameters.Add("@dout", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = dateOut;
```

Не забываю открывать соединение:
`conn.openConnection(); if(command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)`

Но запрос в postgres выдаёт ошибку.
"Столбец"cnumberclient" не существует".
Не видит postgres параметры
Можете помочь?

Comment: Здесь нужно задавать вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: ахах, сорян. Параметры postgres не видит. Не знаю почему

Comment: Отредактируйте пост, переведите вопрос.

Comment: Сделано. Можете помочь с вопросом?

Comment: Я не силен в ADO.NET, если наугад, то попробуйте пробел перед `@cnumberclient` добавить.

Comment: та же история, это не помогло

Comment: Отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64420912/5045688 - The statement DO is server side statement that doesn't support parametrisation.